# Unable to get jQuery image slider to work

Tags: jquery, image, slider, gallery

I've been struggling with this for several days - I purchased a jQuery image slider plugin awhile ago for my site, and have been trying to implement it, but for reasons I cannot understand, it simply refuses to work. I've sent an email to the developer who replied saying that I had installed the coding required correctly, and I've tried re-installing the plugin multiple times, following the instructions closely, but I'm still unable to get my plugin to work. It simply shows up as a blank from my local site. A few free plugins/image slider tutorials I've tried also yielded the same problems, in spite entering the codes correctly, my images show up stacked on top of each other instead of in a nice, smooth slider.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>LITESTAR</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="script/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Google Webfonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- LayerSlider styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layerslider/css/layerslider.css" type="text/css" />

    <!-- jQuery with jQuery Easing JS -->
    <script src="layerslider/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="layerslider/jQuery/jquery-easing-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- LayerSlider from Kreatura Media -->
    <script src="layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
                        skin : 'lightskin',
                        skinsPath : '../layerslider/skins/'
                    });
                });     
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Corporate Overview</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Capabilities</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
           <li><a href="#">Solutions &amp; Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Biometric &amp; RFID Access Control Systems</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Video Surveillance Systems</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Track &amp; Trace Systems</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logistic Management Systems</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Professional IT &amp; Office Equipment</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Document Management Systems</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Infrastructure (Connectivity)</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Systems Integration</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects &amp; Solutions Deployment</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Outsourced Professional Services</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">ACTAtek, Certis, Bioguard, ArtecID</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">HIKVISION, AXIS, microlight</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Customised RFID Asset Tracking System</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cristal WMS, RFID Smart Tag</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Microsoft, Supermicro, HP, IBM</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">CareInc eForm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Support &amp; Download</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Corporate Brochure</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Product Brochure</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Latest News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--End Header-->
      <div id="wrapper">
      <!--LayerSlider begin-->
       <div id="layerslider" style="display:block;">
      <!--LayerSlider layer-->
        <div class="ls-layer">

            <!--LayerSlider background-->
            <img class="ls-bg" src="images/banner1.png" alt="layer1-background" />
            </div>
            <!--LayerSlider layer-->
        <div class="ls-layer">

            <!--LayerSlider background-->
            <img class="ls-bg" src="images/banner2.png" alt="layer1-background" />
            </div>
         <!--LayerSlider layer-->
        <div class="ls-layer">

            <!--LayerSlider background-->
            <img class="ls-bg" src="images/banner3.png" alt="layer1-background" />
            </div>
         <!--LayerSlider layer-->
        <div class="ls-layer">

            <!--LayerSlider background-->
            <img class="ls-bg" src="images/banner4.png" alt="layer1-background" />
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!--End Wrapper-->
      <div id="footer"> </div>
      <!--End Footer--> 
    </div>
    <!--End Container-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in a developer console like firebug / a native browser one?

Comment: check with firebug if all scripts and css have been properly loaded

Comment: @pbaris how do I go about doing this? I have firebug, but I'm not sure how exactly to use it to check errors.

Comment: @GeertJaminon I am using both Chrome and Firefox, but I'm not really clear on how to use it to check errors.

Comment: in firebug open HTML tab and in the DOM tree find the script nodes. Open the nodes and check if scripts are properly loaded. If they are loaded you will see the script itself or else a message NOT found or something similar

Comment: @pbaris Hi, when I open the DOM tree I see a lot of things.. is there anything in particular I should be looking out for? [link] (http://i47.tinypic.com/122n2n8.jpg)

Comment: @user1711308 As i can see in your image you opened the DOM tab. Open the HTML tab and in the DOM tree that you see there (in HTML tab) open the head node an check (open) every script, link nodes (tags) to see if they are properly loaded. I repeat not in the DOM tab in HTML tab https://dl.dropbox.com/u/91000106/Screenshot.png

Comment: @pbaris thanks for your help, I managed to check as you instructed and as far as I can see the scripts I've inserted have loaded properly. Currently, I've succeeded in getting the images to show and change to the next slide, but they are not working anything like how they are supposed to as per the plugin I purchased.

Comment: @user1711308 can you put your file in a server and give us link to see it further, because i don't have this scripts locally